# How to pass command line args to buildSrc project in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to the buildSrc project in Gradle. buildSrc lives inside the main project and if I pass the command line args with -P then the main project receives them but not buildSrc. The reason I need this is because I am trying to pass maven repository's credentials to buildSrc which in turn uses it to resolve dependencies of its sub-projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems we can no pass the command line arguments to both of them in one go. But it is possible to pass the values with -P separately to both buildSrc/build.gradle and project's build.gradle.